# UITabBarItem title in centre of title, not at bottom

Tags: ios, uitabbaritem

I want to make place tabbaritem.title in centre of item, it's possible? I'm trying make image with text in center and create custom tabbaritem, but it looks awful.Help me please.

Answer (score 4):

Try with the iOS5 Appearance Proxy:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0, -2.0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `setTitlePositionAdjustment::[UIOffsetMake(<#CGFloat horizontal#>, <#CGFloat vertical#>)]` ?

If that doesn't work, why don't you create your own control? Have it subclass NSObject and implement the UIImageView with the centered text